# templated operator assignment overload not getting called

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class like below. I have overloaded the assignment operator. The overloaded assignment operator never gets called when I assign one variable to another. It looks like compiler is generating a default assignment operator and calling that. Any reason for that?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
  X()
  {
    cout<<"X()"<<endl;
  }
  X& operator=( X&)
  {
    cout<<"X=()"<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  X<int> a;
  X<int> b = a;
}
```

Output:

```
X()
```

Expected output:

```
X()
X=()
```

Comment: I don't think the assignment operator is getting called, might be default copy constructor

Comment: Note your assignment operator must return something, otherwise it invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X<int> b = a;` is initialization, not assignment, so the copy constructor is called.

This syntax is called **copy initialization**. It's similar to `X<int> b(a)`.

To get an assignment:

```
X<int> b;
b = a;
```

Also note that a proper assignment operator would look like:

```
X& operator=(const X&)
{
   //...
   return this;
}
```